# HQL query for fetching data from a table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to write a hql as  like this

```
Select * from tableName where columnName= null or columnName=0
```

As i am new to this please help me out

Comment: hibernate documentation is here http://www.hibernate.org/docs

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
select column1, column2,....
from tableName
where (columnName = null or columnName = 0)
```

There are some useful tutorials below:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm
http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/index.shtml
http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/HqlTutorial#HHQLWHEREClause

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write

```
FROM PojoName pojo WHERE pojo.property is null or  pojo.property=0
```